# Button changes direction when layout direction is rtl

Tags: android

i'm working on app which completely made in Hebrew (RTL), i set in manifest supportRtl to true and in styles:

```
<item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
<item name="android:textDirection">rtl</item>
```

In one of my activities i have FragmentViewPager which takes the most of the screen and in the bottom i added button to allow go to next fragment (i disabled the option to swipe the pager) .

The problem is when i click on the button (nextButton) the pager swipes the fragment but the button itself changes the sides (was on the right side of the screen and jumps to left side), and when i continue to click on it to go to next pages it stay on the left side, if i change the side in my xml to make it appear on the right side it will jump to right side at the first click.

Here is the code of the button xml:

```
<Button
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_regular"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_button"
        android:id="@+id/next_btn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>
```

As you can see i set it to be to end of the parent.

It looks like the activity get re-rendered when pager changes page, but why it causes changing of the direction?

I will add gif of the screen so you can see better the issue.
 [image]

*I added 4 same fragments to the pager just to test it work .